# XML-Schema : maxOccurs , minOccurs

Tags: xml, xsd

When I run my code it gives me this error

```
[ s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'maxOccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'.]
```

Here is my Schema :

```
<xs:element name="parameters" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element ref="p ?"/> 
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: That's not your full schema. Context is important with `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`. They are related to a group. In what context is your `xs:element` defined? You can declare `top-level` elements, but they can't have maxOccurs or minOccurs since they are not in a context. Edit your question and paste the full context (from the root of your schema).

Comment: Also `p ?` is invalid as the value of `ref`. If you mean *one or none* you can use `<xs:element ref="p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>` (you can omit `maxOccurs="1"` because it's default)

Comment: The thing to remember here is that every XML document can have "exactly one single root element" so that's why you basically cannot specify max and min values for the root--it's implied max+max of 1, so it doesn't even allow you to specify any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<xs:element>` may be declared at top-level (below `xs:schema`) but it can't have `minOccurs` or `maxOccurs` since that doesn't make any sense without a context. If it's root it can only have one element, if it's not, that information refers to the context of the parent element. This is legal:

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="parameters">...</xs:element>
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

but this is not:

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="parameters" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">...</xs:element>
...
</xs:schema>
```

You can *refer* to a top level `xs:element` within a group such as `xs:sequence`. Here you *can* use these attributes because now you have a context (how many are allowed in this group). This is legal:

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element ref="parameters" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="parameters">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element ref="p" minOccurs="0"/> 
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

Here `<parent>` is the context where `<parameters>` occurs, so you can say how many times it's allowed in there. The definition of `<parameters>` is global and you use the `ref` attribute to refer to it.

If you never need to reuse `parameters` or if you are never going to have `parameters` as root, you don't need it at top-level and can nest it inside your `parent` definition. In this case you can use the `name` attribute with `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`.

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="parameters" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
                     <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:all>
                               <xs:element ref="p" minOccurs="0"/> 
                          </xs:all>
                     </xs:complexType>
                 </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    ...
</xs:schema>
```

You can also refer to a top-level *type*. It's more common to reuse, extend and restrict types, so this is also a valid (and recommended) way to define your element:

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="parameters" type="ParameterType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="ParameterType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element ref="p" minOccurs="0"/> 
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    ...
</xs:schema>
```